# Automatic .jar creation

Tags: java, spring, docker, github, dockerhub

Is there a way to create a .jar file for a Spring app on Github?

I need to publish the image of my app on the Dockerhub. I turned on automatic builds on Dockerhub for my develop branch, but the building is failing because the .jar file is missing on the github. And I don't want to manually create .jar file on my machine and push it after every change in code.

Is there a way to somehow make creation of .jar file automatic?

Comment: You could use a multi-stage build to build the `.jar` file from the Java sources.  Then it would only depend on things in your repository.